# C++ heap sort algorithm crashing after 4100+ data entries?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

I have developed the following heap sort algorithm code, but for some reason it works perfectly fine up until a certain (around the 4100 region), after which the program is forced to close?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
void heap_from_root(MVector &v, int i, int n) {

    int end=n,j=0;

    // Identify the lowest root and how many sons it has. If it only has one son, set j=1.
    if (n==1) { n = 0; j = 1; }
    else if ((n-2) % 2 == 0) { n = (n-2)/2; }
    else if ((n-1) % 2 == 0) { n = (n-1)/2; j=1; }

    while (i <= n) { // Start from the lowest root, and go up until the highest root.

        if (j==0) { // If 2 sons, then check for the biggest value. If the biggest value is greater than root, exchange.

            if (v[2*n+1] > v[2*n+2] && v[2*n+1] > v[n]) { v.swap(2*n+1,n); }
            if (v[2*n+2] > v[2*n+1] && v[2*n+2] > v[n]) { v.swap(2*n+2,n); }

        }

        if (j==1) { // If 1 son, if the son's value is greater than the root, exchange.

            if (v[2*n+1] > v[n]) { v.swap(2*n+1,n); }
            j=0; // As only the last root can only have one son, set j to 0.

        }

        n--; // Go backwards to the next root.

    }

    /* The top value of the heap will now be the biggest value. If the heap hasn't been completed sorted, 
    put the biggest value at the END of the heap, and restart the algorithm, this time excluding that last 
    value. Repeating this recursively will mean the heap will be sorted in ascending order. This saves using
    significant excess memory. */

    if (i < end) { v.swap(i,end); end--; heap_from_root(v,i,end); }

}

void heap(MVector &v) { heap_from_root(v,0,v.size()-1); }
```

The MVector class is:

```
// class MVector contains arrays that can work with doubles
class MVector
{   
  // storage for the new vector class 
  vector<double> v;
  public:
    // constructor
    explicit MVector(){}
    explicit MVector(int n):v(n){srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));}
    explicit MVector(int n,double x):v(n,x){}
    // equate vectors;
    MVector& operator=(const MVector& X)
    {if(&X==this)return *this;v=X.v;return *this;}
    // access data in vector 
    double& operator[](int index){ return v[index]; }
    // access data in vector (const)
    double operator[](int index) const { return v[index]; }
    // size of vector
    int size() const {return v.size();}
    void push_back(double x){v.push_back(x);}
    void swap(int i,int j) { double c; c=v[i]; v[i] = v[j]; v[j] = c;  }
    void initialise_random(double xmin, double xmax) {
        const unsigned n = this->size();
        for(unsigned i=0;i<n;i++) {
            v[i] = xmin + rand()*(xmax - xmin) / static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX);
        }
    }

    bool cmp(int i, int j) { 
        if (v[i] < v[j]) { return true; } 
        else { return false; } 
    }
}; // end class MVector
```

And its being initiated with

```
int main ()
{
    MVector x(4500);
    x.initialise_random(0,10);
    double y0 = timer();
    Sort::heap(x);
    double y = timer();

    std::cout << abs(y-y0) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it to see **where** it crashes? Can you give us an [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: What is i? You never change i anywhere in your code.

Comment: Hi @Dukeling, that has been changed now and I believe it should work.

Comment: Also, it seems that you are using `j` as some kind of boolean value - using variables of type `bool` leads to more readable code.

Comment: Sorry I do apologise to everyone, prob should have included the fact that I'm quite new to C++! When ran with debugging, the error seems to be occurring at this point: `size_type size() const
  { // return length of sequence
  return (this->_Mylast - this->_Myfirst);
  }`

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you already have a Min-heap and you're trying to sort it in-place? Or are you trying to create a heap from an unordered array? One potential problem you have is that you're doing this recursively, and your recursion depth will always be N--the length of the list. That's definitely going to run out of memory if your heap is large enough. You should consider using a loop rather than recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an observation. You have this code:

```
if (n==1) { n = 0; j = 1; }
else if ((n-2) % 2 == 0) { n = (n-2)/2; }
else if ((n-1) % 2 == 0) { n = (n-1)/2; j=1; }
```

Consider that when `n` is odd, `n/2 == (n-1)/2`. And when `n` is even, `(n-1)/2 == (n-2)/2`. So you can replace all that code with:

```
if ((n % 2) == 1) { j = 1; }
n = (n-1)/2;
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually was really useful! Cheers :)